# Estou tentando colocar um timer no meu código python

Tags: python

Neste código eu pretendo colocar um timer antes de cada click, este timer precisa aguardar de 2 a 5 segundos e o tempo deve ser aleatório, por exemplo 2,4 segundos, 3,1 segundos, sempre um tempo aleatório antes de cada click. como vcs fariam isto galera? sou novo e estou tendo dificuldades ;-;

```
def compra_item(self, driver, link):
        self.logger.info("Abrindo.")
        driver.get(link)
        self.logger.info("Clicando...")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn_big.color").click()
        self.logger.info("Confirmando...")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type=submit]").click()

        main_text = driver.page_source
        if "flashNoticeInfo" in main_text:
            msg = driver.find_element_by_id('flashNoticeInfo').text
            self.logger.info(msg)
        self.logger.info("Retornando.")
```

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais fácil é usar um delay em conjunto com um tempo aleatório.

```
import time
from random import uniform

numero_aleatorio = uniform(2,5)) #Gera um numero aleatório entre 2 e 5
time.sleep(numero_aleatorio )   # Aplica um delay com base no número aleatório
```